# Integral of derivative of Heaviside function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Suppose I have a function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\,\,\,&\text{if}\,\,\, x<a,\\
0\,\,\,&\text{if}\,\,\, x>a,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a positive number, and suppose I want to compute the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx.
\end{equation}
We try to do this in two different ways.

1. We simply insert $f(x)$ and note that we need to compute the integral separately for the two different intervals:
   \begin{equation}
   \int_0^{\infty}\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx = \int_0^a2xdx = a^2.
   \end{equation}
2. We rewrite $f(x)$ using the Heaviside step function and then integrate.
   We get
   \begin{equation}
   f(x) = x^2(1-H(x-a)),
   \end{equation}
   which means that
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{df(x)}{dx} = 2x(1-H(x-a))-x^2\delta(x-a),
   \end{equation}
   where we have used the product rule for distributional derivatives described [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_Rule_for_Distributional_Derivatives_of_Distributions_multiplied_by_Smooth_Functions), and the fact that the derivative of the Heaviside function is the Dirac delta.
   Inserting this into the integral gives us
   \begin{equation}
   \int_0^{\infty}\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx = \int_0^{\infty}\left(2x(1-H(x-a))-x^2\delta(x-a)\right)dx = \int_0^a2xdx - \int_0^{\infty}x^2\delta(x-a)dx = a^2-a^2 = 0.
   \end{equation}

Why don't I get the same answer? I realize it probably has to do with misuse of distributions, but I can’t seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does the integral you want to compute mean? The function is discontinuous, so its derivative is not well-defined everywhere, and one can consider the distributional derivative, which is in general different from computing the derivative almost everywhere. The distributional derivative is a measure that is not absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure so one cannot cut the integral on $(0,a)$ and $(a,\infty)$ but the set $\{a\}$ has to be considered as well.

So everything is about the choice of derivative: distributional or classical derivative except where it is undefined. The same is true for the Heaviside function. Its classical derivative is $0$ except at $x=0$ where is it undefined.

The distributional derivative is often preferred because it keeps the fundamental theorem of calculus. Here, $\int_0^\infty f' = f(\infty)-f(0)=0$.